# Capacitor and Resistor Values on Headphone Amp Out (highpass filter)

Tags: audio, headphones

I'm more of a programmer than someone who knows electronics. Just trying to figure out what forumlas/method to get the right capacitor and resistor values in my headphone out circuit here. Would you kind folks be able to help me out with these calculations?

I have attached a photo snippet from my kicad schematic here (I have chosen the values 300uF and 10k as a placeholder). Essentially what's happening is the audio codec that I'm using, which I am stuck with for reasons I won't get into, only has a headphone out that uses a virtual ground (1.65V), so it's really meant to be plugged into headphones only. So I'm trying to fool-proof my design so if the headphones get plugged into something like a line-in on an amplifier that shares the power source of my device, it won't cause any problems.

The headphone signal which is centered at 1.65V leaves the audio codec, it goes into the capacitor that removes the DC Offset, there is then a resistor afterwards which serves to charge the capacitor on power up to remove the pop when headphones will be plugged in and out. I also have the headphone signal connected to a solid state relay, which will wait 2 seconds after my device is powered on before closing the circuit at that point (so the capacitor has time to fully remove the dc offset), so that if the headphones are already plugged in on power up they will be protected from the dc thump too.

As far as I'm aware this essentially creates a highpass RLC filter. The headphones are the inductor, and usually headphones are somewhere between 15-30 impedance. Ideally I'm trying to get the cutoff point lower than 40Hz so that the phasing and cutoff are lower than what the headphones are capable of outputting. Also I was told the size of the capacitor will also introduce more resistance into the signal which may or may not be an issue. **What forumlas/calculations do I employ to set the ideal capacitor and resistance values to get a cutoff point of 40Hz or less?** Tysm!

[image: Headphone Out Circuit]

EDIT: adding the photo of the solid state relay IC I'm using

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to find a formula for RC filter cutoff? Basically, what have you already figured out and where are you stuck, so we don't repeat what you already know?

Comment: Yes I have the formula for just the RC filter cutoff C = 1/(2πfR)

But this doesn't account for the headphone impedance or the resistance the capacitor itself adds to the circuit, right?

Comment: I just want to get capacitor and resistor values that will create a cutoff frequency point around 40Hz. The headphone impedance will vary of course, and I'm don't know how much resistance the capacitor itself adds to the signal, if that affects the cutoff point.

Comment: It does, but only if you set R to be the headphone impedance and resistance of the capacitor. However, the capacitor resistance may be so small that it barely matters, so usually you don't bother adding that to the calculations. The point is that the capacitor can already have 20% tolerance and given the large range of headphone impedances, after getting into the right ballpark, few tens or hundreds of milliohms difference is not going to matter much.

Comment: Okay, cool, thank you. So ignoring the headphone and capacitor resistance. Using the forumla above with the values 300uF for C and 10k for R

C = 1/(2πfR)
0.0003 = 1/(2πf10000)
f = 0.053 Hz

Does that look correct?

Comment: No, because what happens if you have 16 ohm headphones connected?

Comment: Okay, so do I just add 16ohm to 10 000 ohms for the calculation?

Comment: The 10k is in parallel with the ~16 ohms of your headphones.  10k in parallel with 16 ohms is ~ 16 ohms.

Comment: No, because they are not in series.

Comment: Ahh, okay got it, so the 10k is actually irrelvant.

Comment: Okay so for a range of headphone impedences between 15ohms and 40 ohms we're looking at a cutoff range of 13.3 Hz and 35.4 Hz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for calculating the RC highpass cutoff is simply Fc = 1/(2*pi*R*C).

So for 300uF and headphone impedances of 15 to 40 ohms the cutoffs are 35 and 13 Hz respectively.

However the solid state relay may be completely unsuitable for passing audio, it's a dual SCR, not an analog multiplexer. It may need 5 to 20 volts to turn on, which is way overboard for a headphone output operating on much lower voltages.

Comment: Regarding the dual SCR. I'm using a buffered digital high signal to turn the SSR on, once it's on are you then saying that the audio signal passing through the load pins will not function properly? I assumed that since it's a relay, as long as it's active it's working just like a closed circuit on the load pins there.

Comment: @DylanMorrison The solid state relay is basically meant for driving mains AC loads. It's meant to be operated with voltages between 5 to 500 VRMS and currents between 5 to 250mA. Because it has zero crossing detection, it needs typically 5V over it before it turns on. It's meant for frequencies between 20 and 500 Hz. So basically, it's unsuitable for passing audio, it most likely never even turns on.

Comment: Oh that's good to know, I will change this to an audio multiplexer!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: @DylanMorrison Not all multiplexers are suitable, as the currents to headphones can be quite large. For example, driving a 1 milliwatt (i.e. the rated sensitivity) to 16 ohms means about 8mA at 128mV. Try to figure out if you even need any switch there. Many devices don't have any switch there and work fine.

Comment: Ahh, okay cool, yea looks like MAX4932 audio multiplexers are what I need, but I'm gonna take your advice and just try the circuit without the switching and see how it goes. If the clicking isn't that bad then it's probably fine.